# Is Mobile Express Checkout Library for Android working on tablet?

Tags: android, paypal, express-checkout

I try to use MECL for Android. Pizza app runs successfully on Android phone, but the app is failed on Xoom and Kindle Fire. This is error message:

```
10-10 19:08:33.538: W/System.err(8731): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 19:08:33.538: W/System.err(8731):     at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
10-10 19:08:33.538: W/System.err(8731):     at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
10-10 19:08:33.538: W/System.err(8731):     at com.paypal.android.a.c.g(Unknown Source)
10-10 19:08:33.538: W/System.err(8731):     at com.paypal.android.a.c.e(Unknown Source)
10-10 19:08:33.538: W/System.err(8731):     at com.paypal.android.a.c.b(Unknown Source)
10-10 19:08:33.538: W/System.err(8731):     at com.paypal.android.a.d.run(Unknown Source)
10-10 19:08:34.984: E/Error(8731): Authentication failed, button not enabled.
10-10 19:08:34.991: W/System.err(8731): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 19:08:34.991: W/System.err(8731):     at com.paypal.android.a.c.a(Unknown Source)
10-10 19:08:34.991: W/System.err(8731):     at com.paypal.android.a.c.e(Unknown Source)
10-10 19:08:34.991: W/System.err(8731):     at com.paypal.android.a.c.b(Unknown Source)
10-10 19:08:34.991: W/System.err(8731):     at com.paypal.android.a.d.run(Unknown Source)
```

- **Anyone success with Pizza app on Android tablet?**
- How to fix this bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: same here, didn't works on Nexus 7 tablet, but it works in Nexus S phone

Comment: TheSpring and @AndroidUser99 did you solved the issue? if yes let me know what you have done

Comment: I have the same problem on  Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.Please if u got the soluation  for this please let me know about it..